# git rebase favoring my branch

Tags: git

I and another developer have been working on a topic branch `topic` for a few days. We have been sharing changes by pushing and merging `topic` from a shared repo.

We have also been keeping up with `master` by merging with it frequently. So, now, our log shows our commits interspersed with the later commits from master.

I would like to rebase so our commits all come after master. Conflicts are plentiful within the files we worked on, but I know that I want to use the `topic` version in all cases.

I tried `git rebase -s recursive -X ours origin/master` but that included both the `topic` version and the `master` version, which is very wrong. I want to only include the `topic` version of files I have worked on.

I then tried `git rebase -s ours origin/master`, but that seems to remove my commits.

What is the correct way to rebase, favoring my changes in `topic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a fun situation. Maybe some variant of what you're trying will work, but I'd try something different.

Let's call the merge commits M1, M2, ..., MN

1. git reset M1^1
2. git rebase M1^2
3. Record the result, e.g. git tag topic-rebased1
4. git reset M2^1
5. git rebase --onto topic-rebased1 M1
6. git rebase M2^2
7. Go back to (3) and repeat until you've rebased all the merges

What you really need is a strategy for doing this in future to not get into this mess.

I suggest something like:

- Do exactly what you did before, except make one person responsible for merging master into the topic branch
- The person responsible for merging also maintains a rebasing branch. Each time they merge master into the non-rebasing branch they also rebase the latest changes from the non-rebasing branch onto the rebasing branch and then rebase the rebasing branch onto master

Yes, I know - it sucks.

Comment: If I had a good workflow that involved two devs working on a topic branch while rebasing onto master, that would be fine. The problem I always run in to is if dev #1 runs `git rebase origin/master`, he can't push to topic any more (requires a force).

Answer (score 2):

During a rebase, "ours" and "theirs" are reversed.